# User Notification emails getting quarantined by Exchange

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an issue with a website I'm building whereby notifications sent via email are being put into quarantine if the recipient is using Exchange or Office 365 emails.

The mails that are getting blocked are those with URLs the confirmation codes for new user registrations, or password reset requests that are generated by the standard Identity Framework.

When the administrator searches for the missing emails, they've been found in the quarantine section and flagged as phishing attempts.

If I send test emails to GMail or ordinary POP accounts, they seem to pass through their spam-detection just fine.

Has anyone else had this problem, and does anyone know why they're being marked as phishing attempts?

Comment: How are you sending emails? Via SMTP? Make sure, the sender email adress domain is equal to the SMTP Mailbox domain. In general, your mail server IP needs a reverse dns for the senders domain.

Comment: I am using MailKit for sending emails, so I'm using SMTP.

Quick additional question. If the mail is being sent from 'mailbox@mydomain.com' but the testing site is 'test.mydomain.com' or 'www.mydomain.com', will that make a difference?

Comment: Where the page is hosted, does not make any difference. It's just all about the mail server, and the headers you give to your email. If your mailbox is mailbox@mydomain.com, your senders email adress should also be mailbox@mydomain.com. Also a correct rDNS is required, which is probably already set, when you have managed email hosting. If this wouldn't be set, you have the same problem my manual sending emails